# Are then any material property solvers (from Charge Density) available in python?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, physical-properties-of-materials, atomic-simulation-environment, atomic-physics

I am looking to predict properties like the Bulk Modulus, total energy, etc., all from the charge density I have as input (CHGCAR file)

Comment: How could you predict bulk modulus from electronic charge density?

Comment: Birch Murugan EOS

Comment: This is a very vague, potentially incorrect question. You should be more specific what kind of methods you are looking for.